# Changing .Less css variables does nothing(SB admin 2 theme)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to customize [SB admin 2 theme](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html) for my asp.net app. I'm using only navbars.

Changing background color was quick and easy. I thought I can use same method to change other stuff but I was wrong apparently.

In my chrome dev tool I see that color: for `<a>` element is stored in `scaffolding.less` file.

When I go there I find this code:

```
a {
  color: @link-color;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: @link-hover-decoration;
  }

  &:focus {
    .tab-focus();
  }
}
```

I think that code means that `<a>` element color is `@link-color` variable.

Now when I go to variables file I find this:

```
@brand-primary:         darken(#428bca, 6.5%); // #337ab7

@link-color:            @brand-primary;
```

So actually brand-primary *is* link color that appears on page, BUT when I change it to for example:

```
@brand-primary:         #ff0000;
```

Nothing happens. Links in navbars still are in this fugly blue color.

How can i track what actually is wrong? Are there any methods to figure out where link color is actually coming from?

Comment: no, browser doesn't understand LESS. you need to convert it to CSS

Comment: do u have <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script> included in your page?